# Android emulator (linux, 2.3.3, x86) booting error

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, haml, kvm

guys
When i try to run emulator with API v10 (2.3.3) on my linux (x64) i get this error:

> emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 111 -> Connection refused
>   emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 22

avd's host gpu option is off

i run my emulator with this commandline:

> emulator64_x86 -avd Nexus_one -verbose -debug all -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm > emulator_debug.txt

file `emulator_debug` is [here](http://pastebin.com/TNDqUbAH)

other APIs (for example, v19 (4.4.2)) works fine with x86 (haml, kvm) even with `gpu on` (booting with `gpu on` succesefully, home screen is empty, but it is a second question)

and one more. about 247 line in debug file. my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is `/home/server/android-sdk/tools/lib`, `lib64OpenglRender.so` there, but i have an error

some ideas?
Hope for help
Thank you for your attention

Comment: follow one of the many tutorials on how to set up your emulator properly.

Comment: what property you mean?

Comment: Please explain more, I don't understand you

Comment: i think that emulator's properties is correct, because if i try to use it with armabi it works good. and same emulator in my mac (with x86 emulation) works good. what's wrong in this configuration, you think?

Comment: This [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27608428/4238076) solved my same problem.